# Is there a way to view the source from a file.obj?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've extracted an object from a file.lib using the /EXTRACT syntax on LIB. Now is there a way to view the source code of this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code is almost certainly not included. Best you can do is disassemble/decompile. Decompilation is far from an exact science, so results may be poor.

Comment: anyway I need to decompile it even if just to see if it works. Is there a decompiler which does it? or is it too hard?

Comment: I use the hex-rays tools. Mostly IDA, which is a disassembler, but they have a decompiler as well. http://www.hex-rays.com/index.shtml (they're not cheap)

Comment: @Samuel - If the function is part of your program, you might step through it with the debugger. The result will be about the same.